# OWL 2 class definition has to make non-binary mention of Self

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, protege, graphdb

I would like to say that a `U. Penn Biobank consenter` is a `Homo sapiens` that has a `consenter role` and participates in a `informed consent process` with at least three elaborations on the `informed consent process`

- It also has the *individual* `U. Penn Biobank Organization` as a participant
- It has a `fully signed consent form` as a specified output

I think I have all of that under control, **but I'm struggling with this:**

- the `consenter role` is realized in the previously mentioned `informed consent process`

Here's what I currently have in Protégé’s `equivalent to` box:

`'Homo sapiens' and 'has role' some 'consenter role' and 'participates in' some ('informed consent process' and ((has_specified_output some 'fully signed informed consent form') and 'has participant' value 'U. Penn Biobank Organization'))`

**How can I say that the `consenter role` is realized in the same `informed consent process` that I have otherwise thoroughly defined?**

Based on comments form @StanislavKralin, I tried adding references to `Self` in the logical definition, but Protégé isn't happy with that, either.  It doesn't seem like you can use `Self` in anything more complex than saying the subject and predicate of a relationship is the same individual, like defining `Narcissist` as a `Homo sapiens` who

`loves Self`

---

EDIT: I think the following says something close to what I had hoped for.  It says that the person has a role that is realized in the `informed consent process`.

`'Homo sapiens’ and 'has role' some ( 'consenter role'  and 'realized in'  some ( 'informed consent process' and ( (has_specified_output some 'fully signed informed consent form') and 'has participant' value 'U. Penn Biobank Organization')))`

Casually, you could say that definition implies that the person participated in the process, but I don't think that will hold axiomatically.  ***I wrote some SPARQL queries to test it, but in retrospect, I think I have been barking up the wrong tree.***

I instantiated `UPBBC1` as an instance of class `U. Penn Biobank consenter` and ran these queries in Ontotext GraphDB with OWL 2 QL reasoning on.  I guess I'll try some other reasoning levels, too.

`PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select * where {
    ?i a ?c .
    ?c rdfs:label "U. Penn Biobank Consenter"
}`

```
+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|                      ?i                       |                          ?c                          
|
+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| <http://transformunify.org/ontologies/UPBBC1> | <http://transformunify.org/ontologies/TURBO_0000502> |
+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

The instance is inferred to be a `Homo sapiens`.

`PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select * where {
    ?i a ?c .
    ?c rdfs:label "Homo sapiens"
}`

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|                      ?i                       |                       ?c                        |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| <http://transformunify.org/ontologies/UPBBC1> | <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/NCBITaxon_9606> |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

But is not inferred to have participated in anything

`PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select * where {
    ?i <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0000056> ?proc
}`

> No data available in table

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, but possibly you just need something like `… and 'has role' o 'realized in' o (inverse 'participates in') Self`. In Manchester syntax, `o` means property chain.

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking of adding the chain `'has role' o 'realized in'` as an equivalent property for `participates in`.  Your suggestion sounds safer.

Comment: @StanislavKralin are you sure property chains can be included in class definitions?  Protege doesn't seem to like it.  It does accept the following:  `'has role' some ('realized in' some (inverse 'participates in' self))`  I'm going to test that now.

Comment: BTW, it seems that non-simple properties can not appear in Self- restrictions :(.

Comment: That's absolutely correct and necessary to let OWL 2 DL be a decidable language, c.f. [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Global_Restrictions_on_Axioms_in_OWL_2_DL)

Comment: @MarkMiller [OWL 2 QL](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_QL) reasoning does neither consider subproperty axioms with property chains nor `self` restrictions.I guess you'd need OWL 2 DL reasoning, which as far as I know only Stardog supports. If allowed by your triple store, custom rules could be more efficient I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, GraphDB doesn't support DL, it supports RL, QL, RDFS, RDFS-Plus and custom rules.

Here's a sample GraphDB rule implementing your case

```
id: Penn_Biobank_consenter
  x <rdf:type> <Homo sapiens>
  x <has role> r
  r <rdf:type> <consenter role>
  r <realized in> p
  p <rdf:type> <informed consent process>
  p <has_specified_output> o
  o <rdf:type> <fully signed informed consent form>
  p <has participant> <U. Penn Biobank Organization>
  p <has participant> x
  -----------------------
  x <rdf:type> <U. Penn Biobank consenter>
```

However, I wouldn't make that a type, I would make it a prop, i.e. the conclusion would be

```
  x <consented to> <U. Penn Biobank research>
```

And I would generalize it to any org conducting research, not just `U. Penn Biobank Organization`:

```
id: consented_to
  x <rdf:type> <Homo sapiens>
  x <has role> r
  r <rdf:type> <consenter role>
  r <realized in> p
  p <rdf:type> <informed consent process>
  p <has_specified_output> o
  o <rdf:type> <fully signed informed consent form>
  p <has participant> org
  p <has participant> x
  org <conducts research> res
  -----------------------
  x <consented to> res
```

with axiom

```
<U. Penn Biobank Organization> <conducts research> <U. Penn Biobank research>
```

(That assumes the org conducts just one kind of research; otherwise you'd have to say that the consent is `about` a particular research.)